# Bound in Ternary Goldbach Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Given an odd number > 7, denoted as m, suppose A(m) = {p_1, p_2, p_3: p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = m}.  Then, A(11) = {3,5}.

Now, is cardinality of A(m) bounded for all odd numbers, or is cardinality of A(m) increases continuously ad m gets bigger?

Comment: Assuming the binary Goldbach conjecture, $A(m)$ contains every odd prime up to $m-6$. We can prove that $A(m)$ contains almost every such odd prime (via the "exceptional set" in the binary Goldbach problem), so the cardinality tends to infinity.